# How to make Energy from radioactive material

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, radioactivity, proton-decay

I have seen where Tritium hitting phosphorus emits light, and a solar cell collects it to for a "battery" of a sort, but Are you able to extract (For Example) Americium from smoke detector and use it do Make light/Power? And could you just use phosphorus from a match or is it more complicated? I only have a basic understanding of radioactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could technically use the americium from smoke detectors, but you'd need quite a bit of it - the activity of americium is relatively low, and the amount is quite small in each detector, in the microgram range. Source: http://www.world-nuclear.org/information-library/non-power-nuclear-applications/radioisotopes-research/smoke-detectors-and-americium.aspx

So, with the right phosphor, you could generate (a very very tiny amount of) power from americium from smoke detectors.

Also, I believe you are confusing the element **phosphorus** with the general concept of a **phosphor**. A phosphor is simply a compound that glows in response to a certain electromagnetic stimulus. Phosphorus is the element that is found on old match-heads, but it is not used in any phosphors that I know of. Most phosphors are made of transition metal or rare-earth metal compounds. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How would you even find the right type of phosphor that would glow from it? Trial and error? Math? Or is it a simple Google search?

Comment: What you're looking for is a material that has a gap in its energy bands that is comparable to the energy of the particle you're throwing at it. These band gaps can be found via Google search.